# The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request while trying to connect signalR endpoint through yarp

Tags: iis, signalr, reverse-proxy, gateway, ms-yarp

I am trying to connect signalR endpoint using **Yarp** as a reverse proxy.

However I faced this error:

[image]

The yarp configuration is:

```
"ReverseProxy": {
    "Clusters": {
        "ws-cluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "ws-destination1": {
            "Address": "http://localhost:8240"
          }  
        }
      }
    },
    "Routes": {
       "dev-ws": {
        "ClusterId": "ws-cluster",
        "CorsPolicy": "any",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "ws/{**catch-all}"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

and the signalR endpoint is:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
        
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<HubService>("/ws");
        endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
    });
}
```

And there is something strange about the **gateway**, when I call `ws://localhost:8000/ws` (The gateway has been hosted on port 8000) inside the server, it works! but if I use its domain
from outside of the server it won't!

Is there a problem with IIS or do I need to apply a specific configuration?

Comment: `if I use its domain from outside of the server it won't!` What error message it reported? Or in another word, Can you acces it through domain? If signalr can be accessed through domain, it must be something wrong with Yarp. Otherwise some restrictions like firewall, security policy block the request from Yarp.

Comment: The error is shown in the picture.
And I can't access it through domain. I guess I should do something about IIS WebSocket protocol.

Comment: That's the issue. If you cannot access it through domain, how yarp can call it through URL. When you access it through domain, what error message it showed? 404 or any other status code? Does the domain is a public domain and can be access in public network?

Comment: Yes it is public domain and as I said the error is shown in the picture I've posted before. I am not sure about the status code but I didn't get any 404. The gateway's log says it's 101.

Comment: 101 means switching protocols. It has prepared to receive requests. The error message in images shows that it call localhost not domain. You should access the domain through client browser. If any thing wrong, browser will return error message.

Comment: The gateway is hosted on domain and also it listens port 8000 which means it can be accessed form outside of the server but other projects are run as console apps and each of them are hosted on particular port. I am using 'Url Rewrite' in IIS to forward all requests to the localhost:8000 (I'm doing this for logging gateway) So all requests are forwarded to other projects and it works for all of them except `SignalR` endpoint.